# Play production mode and writing public folder

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, centos6.5

I have a problem writing files into a public folder when I run my play 2.4 application on my Centos 6.5 server.
When I run the following command line:

```
./activator clean compile run
```

The application has no problems to write files in the `public/` folder.

But with `./activator clean compile start`

I get some java exceptions and the files are not created.

Comment: May be the running process does not have the required permissions to do that.

Comment: In dev or production mode, this is Java process with same user.

Comment: I have fixed some minor grammar mistakes and capitalization errors, as well as the code formatting. You should include more information about the java exceptions you are getting, and make the title summarize the problem better (I lack the required playframework knowledge). Thanks!

Comment: The true problem is i have trouble accessing the compiled assets location in production.                                                                        I use new File("public/) so a public folder will be created in /target/universal/stage/ folder, instead of current public folder

Comment: Solved with String basePath = Play.application().path().getPath();

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see is the first command "activator run" will run the code in dev mode so you can update the files in public folder but when you use "activator start" then this will run the code from the production mode so It will not allow you to change anything in public folder.